# dplyr mutate - How to properly apply custom function with mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to migrate a database and would like to use R to assist in the process. As part of the migration process, I need to update "Item IDs" as they have changed. I have created a function to map the old id's to the new:

```
old_to_new <- function(id, df) {
  return (df[which(df$Old == id), ]$New)
}
```

However, whenever I attempt to apply it to add a new column in my dataframe (loaded from an database table):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RODBC)

cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;")
df <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT * FROM [MaintDB_New].[dbo].[Priority]")
ticket_df <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT * FROM [MaintDB_New].[dbo].[Tickets]")
ticket_details_df <- sqlQuery(cn, "SELECT * FROM [MaintDB_New].[dbo].[Ticket_Details]")
new_items <- read_csv("./ticket_itm_export_temp.csv", col_names = c("Old", "Name", "New"))

ticket_df_new <- ticket_df %>% mutate(item_id = old_to_new(itemID, new_items))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, col, value = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_,  : 
  replacement has 280 rows, data has 69430
In addition: Warning message:
In df$Old == id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

What am I doing wrong, and what is the proper approach. I received a similar error while attempting to use `ddplyr`.

I am new to R, so I apologize if this an obvious question.

EDIT - Added data structure:

```
    head(ticket_df)
  ticketID propertyID itemID roomNumber assignedToID isOpen openID latestID
1       11         10      1       <NA>           NA      0     22       23
2       12         17      1       <NA>           NA      0     24      289
3       13         17      1       <NA>           NA      0     25      292
4       14         17     17       <NA>           NA      0     26     4411
5       15         17     68       <NA>           NA      0     27      296
6       16         17     74       <NA>           NA      0     28      294

head(new_items)
           Old Name                    New
      <int> <chr>                 <int>
    1   257 Register Cash Drawers   425
    2   253 Alarm System            426
    3   135 CREDENZA/ ARMOIRE       427
    4    55 Back Office PC          428
    5   183 Backup All Data         429
    6   260 Base Boards             430
```

Links to dput output: [ticket_df](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8ygo9r284nljzo/ticket_df.txt?dl=0) and [new_items](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l8ygo9r284nljzo/ticket_df.txt?dl=0)

Comment: I'd suggest just doing a `left_join`, something like `ticket_df %>% left_join(new_items, by = c("id" == "Old")) %>% mutate(item_id = New)`. Also make sure `new_items` doesn't have duplicate `Old` entries or you'll end up with more rows than your started with. If this doesn't work, please post reproducible sample data so we can see what's going on. Use `dput` to give us a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of the relevant data frames (looks like `ticket_df` and `new_items` are the relevant ones here).

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I do not believe that will work for me. I have added the outputs from head for the first data frames.

Comment: Your data is still incomplete: there is nothing to tie things together between frames (no common "key"). (And please use `dput`.)

Comment: @r2evans - itemID (in ticket_df) is a foreign key that would reference values in the "Old" column in "new_items". The "new_items" object is not a direct database export; I am using it as an intermediary structure to map old ids to new.

Comment: One thing about reproducible questions: the representative data needs to indicate the behavior you're trying to demonstrate. In this case, there are no matches between `ticket_df$itemId` and `new_items$Old`, so any code we might work on will do nothing. (I was trying to infer "key" based on finding any columns with matches. Thank you for clarifying the underlying data structure, so we now just need a more representative data sample ... and please use `dput`.)

Comment: Thanks. I have attached the output of dput, for the `new_items` object and the first 1000 rows of `ticket_df` (it is a decent sized dataset).

Comment: I answered by changing your sample data (in the question) to give us matches. In general, many people eschew links (e.g., dropbox) in questions for two reasons: (1) hesitation to download random binary files due to the risk of viruses, etc; (2) when those links go stale, this question is no longer reproducible. The goal, keep as much as possible encapsulated within the question text as possible. This suggests trimming sample data and code to the smallest necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (really!) think Gregor's comment of `left_join`ing makes a lot of sense. I'll force some matches by changing some of your values:

```
new_items$Old[1:2] <- c(17L,74L)
```

Now the join:

```
library(dplyr)

ticket_df %>%
  left_join(select(new_items, Old, New), by=c("itemID" = "Old"))
#   ticketID propertyID itemID roomNumber assignedToID isOpen openID latestID New
# 1       11         10      1         NA           NA      0     22       23  NA
# 2       12         17      1         NA           NA      0     24      289  NA
# 3       13         17      1         NA           NA      0     25      292  NA
# 4       14         17     17         NA           NA      0     26     4411 425
# 5       15         17     68         NA           NA      0     27      296  NA
# 6       16         17     74         NA           NA      0     28      294 426
```

If you're satisfied that this works, just reassign:

```
ticket_df %>%
  left_join(select(new_items, Old, New), by=c("itemID" = "Old")) %>%
  mutate(itemID = if_else(is.na(New), itemID, New)) %>%
  select(-New)
#   ticketID propertyID itemID roomNumber assignedToID isOpen openID latestID
# 1       11         10      1         NA           NA      0     22       23
# 2       12         17      1         NA           NA      0     24      289
# 3       13         17      1         NA           NA      0     25      292
# 4       14         17    425         NA           NA      0     26     4411
# 5       15         17     68         NA           NA      0     27      296
# 6       16         17    426         NA           NA      0     28      294
```

Alternatively you can use `mutate(itemID = coalesce(New, itemID))`, thanks @Gregor.

---

However, if you need to use a function (perhaps your problem is more complicated or you need something more generic), then a note:

- Generally, functions used within `mutate` need to return vectors of length 1 or the same length as what was given to it; this means subsetting (as you did with `df[which(df$Old == id), ]$New`) will often not work. (If you can *guarantee* that it will always return length 1 then it will not error, but I'm guessing that is not safe.). Similarly, `summarize` requires (I believe) functions to return length 1.

Here's one thought that is a little hasty but gets the same results:

```
myfunc <- function(id, changes) {
  ind <- match(id, changes[["Old"]])
  indnonna <- !is.na(ind)
  id[which(indnonna)] <- changes[["New"]][ind[indnonna]]
  id
}

ticket_df %>%
  mutate(newid = myfunc(itemID, new_items))
#   ticketID propertyID itemID roomNumber assignedToID isOpen openID latestID newid
# 1       11         10      1         NA           NA      0     22       23     1
# 2       12         17      1         NA           NA      0     24      289     1
# 3       13         17      1         NA           NA      0     25      292     1
# 4       14         17     17         NA           NA      0     26     4411   425
# 5       15         17     68         NA           NA      0     27      296    68
# 6       16         17     74         NA           NA      0     28      294   426
```

You can obviously just assign directly to `itemID` instead of a different column. I still discourage this, as (1) joins are much more efficient; (2) I'd want to work with the function a bit more to perhaps find a more robust method; and (3) it hard-codes the structure of `new_items` (i.e., specific column names) into the function, whereas doing a join allows you to specify at join time what happens, keeping the code immediately next to the structure-using elements.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for both a working answer and explanation. Wish I could give you more upvotes (and thanks to Gregor for the left_join recommendation).

Comment: Minor comment to a nice answer: `dplyr` ports the handy `coalesce` function from some SQL flavors as to take the first non-missing value, simplifying if_else(is.na(New), itemID, New)` to `coalesce(New, itemID)`.

Comment: I was juggling a couple of other things and tried `coalesce` but it didn't work ... not sure why, it's working now, thanks @Gregor.